# Overlay div with position absolute and height 100% not moving with the scroll

Tags: css, css-position

please look [here](http://codepen.io/MickelSierra85/pen/XKpxdE) and click the on button.

```
.darkClass
{
    background-color: white;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* IE */
    opacity: 0.9; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.9; /* FireFox */
    z-index: 2000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

}

You will see that the overlay div is covering the whole screen as desired, but when I scroll it isn't moving with the scrolling as expected.

I would like to see the grey overlay moving with my scrolling.

what am I missing here CSS-wise?

Comment: you need to use `position:fixed;` on the `.darkClass` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.

It'll position element relative to the browser window and not relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

Answer (score 1):

To let the Overlay stay at the top use position:fixed.
The height depends on the size of the screen, not of the content. So your overlay fills the complete screen but not the complete content